# Laravel 5.2.29 session::flash lost instantly

Tags: php, laravel, session, flash-message

I created a new laravel project and laravel flash seems to not be working as i want. The moment I return to a route the flash is gone. I have controller method that does absolutly nothing but flash and return to a route.

Like so

```
public function activateContract(Request $request ){
    return redirect()->to('test')->with('status', 'test');
}
```

My routes file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();
Route::get('/', function(){
    return redirect()->intended(route('contract.index'));
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'contract'], function(){
        Route::get('', ['as' =>  'contract.index' , 'uses' => 'User\ContractController@index']);
        Route::post('', ['as' =>  'contract.index' , 'uses' => 'User\ContractController@activateContract']);
        Route::get('mijn', ['as' =>  'user.contract.index' , 'uses' => 'User\ContractController@userContracts']);
    });

});


Route::get('test', function(){
    dd(session('status'));
});
c});
```

Here is the ouput of the die dump in the test route witch magicaly lost the flash message.

```
null
```

Comment: Did you modify the 'web' middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php?
It should look like this:  

`'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        ]`

Comment: Didnt edit it and checked its the same as in your comment.

Comment: Well i guess im just going to have to use put then... and dispose it at the bottom of my master template.

Comment: Could you try this in a fresh installation of Laravel? I think something may have changed in your current project

Comment: Works fine on a fresh install. All other projects on my dev machine work fine to. Im just gona start over i think then no idea could of have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the message with the redirect like so:

```
return redirect()->to('test')->with('status', 'test');
```

And then you can access it with the session helper function:

```
session('status');
```

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Edit: Place your `Route::get('test')` into your group with middleware 'web'.
See more about HTTP Middleware [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#registering-middleware)

Comment: session('status');  returns null aswell.

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Could you update your answer with what your new code? I tried this and it worked (also in Laravel 5.2.29).

Comment: I know it should work used the same flash message in a dozen other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.2 changed middleware document as :Keep in mind, the web middleware group is automatically applied to your default routes.php file by the RouteServiceProvider.

It means that if you keep a route in another ['middleware' => 'web'], the data set by session()->flash() would be lost by executed web middleware twice.

It is also the answer someone asked why web executed twice.

[Laravel 5.2 : Web middleware is applied twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069203/laravel-5-2-web-middleware-is-applied-twice)