# Laravel 5.2 : Web middleware is applied twice

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

Here is my routes.php code

```
    Route::auth();

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth','role:Admin']], function(){

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get('user/data', ['as' => 'admin.user.data','uses'=>'UserController@userData']);
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');

    Route::get('merchant/data', ['as' => 'admin.merchant.data','uses'=>'MerchantController@merchantData']);
    Route::resource('merchant', 'MerchantController');

    Route::get('bcategory/data', ['as' => 'admin.bcategory.data','uses'=>'BusinessCategoryController@bcategoyData']);
    Route::resource('bcategory', 'BusinessCategoryController');

    Route::get('ccategory/data', ['as' => 'admin.ccategory.data','uses'=>'CouponCategoryController@ccategoyData']);
    Route::resource('ccategory', 'CouponCategoryController');

    Route::delete('image/{image}', ['as' => 'admin.image.destroy','uses'=>'ImageController@destroy']);

    Route::put('image/{image}/primary', ['as' => 'admin.image.updateprimary','uses'=>'ImageController@setPrimaryImage']);
});

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Merchant', 'prefix' => 'merchant', 'middleware' => 'role:Merchant'], function(){

 });
});
```

[image: Route list in php artisan route:list]

*Can anybody please tell me why web route is applied twice i have added only once to group middleware.?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes are made to always invoke the `web` middleware in a `RouteServiceProvider` so no need to specify it in `routes.php` going forward.

Updated [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups) says:

***Keep in mind, the `web` middleware group is automatically applied to your default `routes.php` file by the `RouteServiceProvider`.***

Answer (score 0):

NOW  the "web" middleware group is applied to default. Delete this `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web']` from you file route.php